# HTML5/JavaScript Media Player

Tags: javascript, html, media

I was experimenting with the new video HTML tags and I've tried to make a web-based media player. I tried using a file upload box to enter the object that should be played and that didn't work, which meant I had to try using a text box. That worked to a certain extent, which is that the src property of the video would be edited, but it would be impossible to play the media.

My source code is as follows:

```
<input type="text" value="Path to file" id="med">
<input type="button" value="Play!"onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('vid2').src=document.getElementById('med').value">
<video width=800 height=400 controls id="vid">
    <source src="" id="vid2">
</video>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked perfectly for me:

```
<input type="text" value="Path to file" id="med">
<input type="button" value="Play!" onclick="document.getElementById('vid2').src=document.getElementById('med').value;">
<video width="800" height="400" controls="controls"  src="" id="vid2"></video>
```

Comment: Did the video play? Because the controls half disappear for me and the play button sort of goes white and then grey again for no reason. :O (Thanks btw.)

Comment: That happens when the video type is not supported

Comment: Ah, ok. I tried an avi instead of a wmv and it worked. Any idea why wmv's don't work? IS it because I installed the Windows media player thingamagig?

Comment: I'm guessing you can't use wmv's with html5 then? Ok then, avi's are ok. Thanks for all the help. :D

Comment: Well AVI won't work for you all the time because AVI is just a video type that is pretty much like a DIV element - it's just a box that you can't know what you'll find in it, so sometimes it will work sometimes it won't.
The most recommended way is to use WebM videos, google it.

Comment: Marking my answer as the answer would be better than a thanks :)

Comment: Oh right, sorry. I'm knew here and I'm still getting my head around the interface.